# Why does my build sometimes do zero damage?

Tags: peglin

In *Peglin* (iOS), with the pictured build, my Peglin does a whole lot of damage. Sometimes, however, the built-up damage of a ball in flight resets to 0, and I don't understand why.

This appears to happen every four times the board refreshes. Especially noticeable when using a Refresh Orb (green "R" orb).

My relics are Peglintuition, Bomb Baton, Brassicaceae Knuckles, Unicorn Horn?, Training Weight, Intentional Oboe, Matryoshka Shell, Special Button, Perfect Forger, and Refillibuster.

My orbs are Stone, Ballad, Daggorb, Refreshorb, and Orblation.

I assume it's some synergetic effect of the relics and the orbs?

[image: build]

Comment: I see you have Peglintuition, Bomb Baton, two Brassicaceae Knuckles, Unicorn Horn?, Training Weight, Intentional Oboe, Matryoshka Shell, Special Button, Perfect Forger, and the Refillibuster?

Comment: That's correct, and you're right about the Unicorn Horn too. I'll add the names to my question

Comment: And I think that final orb is https://peglin.fandom.com/wiki/Orblation

My best guess is something about having too much Muscircle or something, but I don't play.

Comment: I wonder if the Matryoshka Shell's debuff to attack power has anything to do with it.

Comment: Do all the pegs go red before your damage goes to zero? If so it could be from the ball's crit damage being zero. On a fresh board with your current relics your peballs are all 0 crit. The muscircle only affects the normal damage.